# How to connect scatter plot points with lines for multi-year data plotted with Julian days?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

I am trying to graph groundwater elevation data for a single site from Sep. 1 - Oct. 31, with a line for each year from 2012-2021. I can create a scatter plot, but whenever I try to connect the points, it connects all the points with the same **JULIAN** values together in order instead of each year having its own line.

*SGT4W3_mean_groundwater.csv* contains all of the data.

**SGT4W3** has 12 variables, of which I am using:

- **value** (groundwater level in feet)
- **DATE** (YYYY-MM-DD in *date* format)
- **JULIAN** (the Julian day 1-365)
- **Month** (1-12, extracted from **DATE**)
- **Year** (2012-2021, extracted from **DATE**)

Here is the code I am working with:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

```
SGT4W3 <- read.csv(
  file = "SGT4W3_mean_groundwater.csv",
  header  =TRUE,
  sep = ",",
  dec = "."
)

SGT4W3$DATE = as.Date(SGT4W3$timestamp, "%m/%d/%Y")
SGT4W3$JULIAN = format(SGT4W3$DATE, "%j")
SGT4W3 = mutate(SGT4W3, Month = month(DATE))
SGT4W3 = mutate(SGT4W3, Year = year(DATE))
SGT4W3$Year = as.numeric(as.character(SGT4W3$Year))
SGT4W3$Year = factor(SGT4W3$Year)

SGT4W3 %>%
  filter(JULIAN >= 244 & JULIAN <= 304) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = JULIAN, y = value,
             fill = Year, color = Year, group = 1)) +
  geom_point(stat = "identity") +
  geom_line(aes(x = JULIAN, y = value, color = Year)) +
  labs(title = "Mean Groundwater Level at SGT4W3 in Sep. & Oct.",
       subtitle = "Data plotted by year",
       x = "Date",
       y = "Groundwater Level (ft NGVD29)",
       caption = "Data pulled from DBHYDRO (https://apps.sfwmd.gov/dbhydroInsights/#/site/SGT4W3)") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(244, 274), labels = c("Sep", "Oct")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray90","gray85","gray80","gray75","gray70","gray65",
                                "gray60","gray55","gray50", "springgreen2")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("gray85","gray80","gray75","gray70","gray65","gray60",
                                "gray55","gray50","gray45", "springgreen3"))
```

I have tried changing `geom_line(aes(x = JULIAN, y = value, color = Year))` to `geom_line(aes(x = Month, y = value, color = Year))`, but it still does not connect the correct points.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As you want a line per year try with `group = Year`.

Comment: PS: For more details on the `group` aes and when and why it is explicitly needed see e.g. https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_group_order.html